# 'Cannot read property 'split' of undefined' for array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, match

I'm trying to split the elements of an array and I'm getting the message 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined'

```
var pattern1 = /[0-9].?[d].?[0-9]/g;
var teste = [];
var teste = rolagem.match(pattern1);

for (var i = 0; i <= teste.length; i++) {
    var meuarray = teste[i].split('d');    
    console.log(meuarray.toString());
};
```

Comment: try to `console.log(teste);` to see if its elements are arrays

Comment: `i < teste.length;` not `<=`, otherwise your code will try to access `teste[teste.length]` but since arrays are 0 indexed the last element is `teste.length-1`

Comment: Yes, it shows the elements.

Comment: Patrick Evans, you're right. Now it's working without the error. Was happening because it was trying to split an empty element?